Oracle Forms fails to start up on OL9 - cannot find shared object file libopmnperf.so
I have freshly installed a 19c Database and an Oracle Forms and Reports 12.2.1.4 instance on an Oracle Linux 9 VM and everything starts properly except for the Forms application. When I try to start up from the web console, it returns the following error:
An exception occurred for task start application formsapp [Version=12.2.1] on cluster_forms.: 
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.1.19/lib/libifopmnwrp.so.0: libopmnperf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

When I navigate to my ORACLE_HOME/lib directory the result of $ ldd libifopmnwrp.so :
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd21556000)
libopmnperf.so => not found
libonssys.so => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1b04c77000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1b04c72000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1b04a69000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1b04e8b000)

I am not sure what is going wrong, I have my LD_LIBRARY_HOME env var set to my $ORACLE_HOME/lib as such:
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
->   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.1.19/lib:/lib:/usr/lib

Verify that you machine has these OS packages installed.  This is the doc for DB19, but same would apply for F/R 12.2.1.19, with the exception that F/R also requires motif.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/supported-oracle-linux-9-distributions-for-x86-64.html
